# sqlalchemy UniqueConstraint not working on postgresal

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

I'm using `sqlalchemy` on postgresql and create a table with multi-column unique constraint as below:

```
MONITOR = Table(
    "monitor",
    METADATA,
    Column("id", BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("watchlist_id", String, index=True),
    Column("term", String),
    Column("match_substring_variations", Boolean),
    Column("nameserver_exclusions", Text),
    Column("text_exclusions", Text),
    Column("created", DateTime(timezone=True)),
    Column("updated", DateTime(timezone=True)),
    UniqueConstraint("term", "text_exclusions", "nameserver_exclusions"),
)
```

however, it's not working. for example, I can keep inserting records with same `term`, `text_exclusions` and `nameserver_exclusions`. Did I miss anything when using `sqlalchemy` to create UniqueConstraint`? Thanks

Comment: Have you added the constraint to your Python side definition after initially creating the table?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for the quick response! Can you elaborate adding constraint to Python side definition?

Comment: While developing have you possibly created the table in your database before adding the `UniqueConstraint` in `Table("monitor", ...)`? If you have, you will need to migrate the database table schema as well.

Comment: this is still in development not production and I'm using docker for postgresql, so I restart postgresql docker but still get this issue.

Comment: I think this may require a [mcve] to get to the bottom of. Could you please provide some sample data and an example of how you insert that data?

Comment: can you elaborate how to migrate schema?